# Relay Specification regarding switching speed

Tags: relay, speed

Newbie here, just wanted to ask some clarification regarding reading datasheet since i don't quite find a standard way to determine switching speed. I already had surf and the closest one was the question by Glavić [What does CPM unit mean in relay specification?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/200920/what-does-cpm-unit-mean-in-relay-specification). This means its maximum operation is 1 cycle every 10 seconds.

I have a school project where I need my relay to have a switching frequency of at least 1 cycle a second and my current relay that i have is this: https://www.digikey.com.au/products/en?keywords=alf1p05. Upon reading its datasheet, i find a max. operating speed 20 times/minutes (does this mean 1 time = 1 cycle = 1 on & off operation?? meaning 1 cycle every 3 seconds?)

[image]

then i find this other relay https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Electric%20Works%20PDFs/jm.pdf having a max.operating speed of 180cpm. (does this mean 180 on & off operation every minute? 1 cycle every 33ms?)

[image]

I hope you can help me at least understand this one clearly, sorry if I'm somewhat indecisive with this one.

edited: i canvas all relays on digikey, mouser, etc and every relay detasheet don't have this 'max.operating speed' spec info like this one https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/418/NG_DS_RT1_1014-729126.pdf, how can i determine the speed of this relay or other relays w/o relying on the max.operating speed spec info?

Comment: Well yes, i even include that link on my question, one has condition, the other one has none, so it does mean that the other relay can operate a cycle on & off w/ 33 milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Panasonic relay should easily be able to switch with a 1 second cycle.

The actual maximum switching speed is **not listed in the datasheet**, at least, I could not find it.

I know for a fact that most relays like can switch at about 5 times per second of faster.

The numbers you did find in the datasheet are not the **limits** but the **conditions** for which other specifications are given. Note how it says "Conditions" in the first column.

So I think this relay will just work for what you want.

If you want to see that in the specification as well then I suggest looking at a different relay, for example from Omron as I have seen datasheets from them where the maximum switching speed is listed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry if i really need some solid clarification, so it means the other relay https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Electric%20Works%20PDFs/jm.pdf can operate 1 cycle on and off w/in 33 millisecond w/o condition.

if i apply 5vdc as my switching signal having a 220vac 10-20amp switching load, this is what i get right off the bat?

also, why almost relay datasheet don't have this specs w/ regards to speed, how can i determine the speed of the relay using other spec info w/o 'max.operating speed'??

Comment: For that Panasonic JM relay it says: *Max. operating speed 180 cpm* so that's 3 times per second on/off. So this relay does have a maximum speed spec. 180 cpm is 3 per second so that's 333 ms and not 33 ms!

Answer (score 1):

note "at normal switching capacity"

With a below normal capacity (lower voltage or lower current) you can switch faster.